# My Particle System just stopped working

Tags: particles

I have a big problem, I just finished making a fairly demanding scene, And i did a render just a while ago, but then i tried importing a tree into the scene before final rendering, it ended up being a bit too much for my computer. So i deleted the tree and got back to rendering, but all of a sudden blender just crashes whenever i try to render.

And it seems like its a problem that has occurred with the particle system, because I can't even turn it off or deleting it without crashing blender, And also before this happened i could render at 60000 particles now it crashes even if i pull it down to 1.

Another thing is, I can disable it from rendering, and at least render without the particles, but it doesn't seem to be a performance issue, as i couldn't even render it at 1 particle.

Do anybody know what might be going on?

(Also just one more thing, I can't even move the object that has the particle system applied to it without crashing blender.)

Comment: Did you cache the particle simulation?

Comment: No, I didnt do anything, as far as i know anyways! All I really did was making a tree, and the tree was making the scene too slow, so i deleted it, and then when i decided to keep the rendering going without the tree, it just didn't work anymore! I even tried appending every object i used to a new blender file, but the particle system crashed the new blender file aswell! 

But is there a way to see if i accidentally cached it?

Comment: It would have been something you would have had to actually do yourself. Maybe try uploading your .blend to [**Blend-Exchange**](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Yes I tried uploading it, but its too big for Blend-exchange, so i uploaded it on google drive, here is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By4AwCMVSPt4aDFRZURZb3AxNHM/view?usp=sharing !

Comment: Blender also stores temp files, and sometimes these may not be cleared. You might have a lot of big sym files somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the source of emission set your key frames back to 0 (it must be 0 even if your animation starts on key frame 50) and hit alt+a, this should reset the animation or I might have missed the boat entirely, ether way it doesn't hurt to try

Comment: Suggestion like this should probably be posted as comments.

Comment: I tried do this, but i don't really see the point with this? the only thing that happens is that it starts the timeframe when i hit alt+a? And the blender still crashes afterwards!

Comment: While I misunderstood the question a bit. What happened to me in the past is the particle system would restart but only go up to a cretin point so I reset the animation. I am sure this is not what you meant. Have you checked if you have an Auto-save of your blend before you added tree

Comment: Oh okay then i get it! Well I've tried looking for one but i haven't found one so far, so i guess there isn't any unfortunately!

Comment: I will try downloading your blend file, and see if I can find the problem, but I am only a noob, I have only worked with blender for 3 years

Comment: Hay, I have downloaded your file, I just want to know what the sizes the file is, because google drive say it is more the 202mb but when I downloaded it it was only 2.8mb. Now when I opened it is said that the file was not complete.

Comment: Yes I think it should be 202 mb, Im not really sure how it actually got to that size, its sounds like a lot, but i think thats the size anyways!

Comment: I was not able to open, the file, I think it because of my computer spec (I am running blender on an old ibm pc) but I am going to a friends house some time this holiday that has a better computer, so it might take some time tell I can give you an answer, sorry for keeping you waiting